# Struts 2 session values not reflecting in JSP in load balanced environment / domain URL

Tags: java, session, struts2, load-balancing

I have a struts 2 application, where I have a link and on clicking on that link, it executes a method inside an action class and redirect the user to another action class which eventually forwards to a JSP page. In that JSP page, I have 3 DIVs where I have included another set of JSP pages. These JSP pages are accessing session values stored in the application, my issue is that these session values are not being displayed. the session values are in there because the moment I hit REFRESH / F5 button they are being displayed correctly.

AND this is happening only in my load balanced (domain URL) environment in Test, it is not happening when the application is accessed using individual server URLs. Please anyone help me on this, need to get this addressed right away. Here is the code that I ahve in my struts.xml which takes care of redirecting to another action class:

```
<action name="newPriceSheet" class="com.customer.catalogui.actions.DisplayCategoryAction" method="showPreviousSelection">
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultLoginStack" />
  <result name="success" type="redirect">
    <param name="location">displayCategory.action</param>
    <param name="parse">false</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

Comment: <action name="newPriceSheet" class="com.customer.catalogui.actions.DisplayCategoryAction" method="showPreviousSelection">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultLoginStack" />
                  <result name="success" type="redirect">
                        <param name="location">displayCategory.action</param>
                        <param name="parse">true</param>
      <!--              <param name="anchor">FRAGMENT</param>-->
                  </result>
      </action>

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not related to Struts2. You need to configure your load balancer to route all requests to the same server when a session has been established. This is typically referred to as session affinity or sticky sessions.

I would advise you to edit your question to provide some more information on what load balancer you are using as well as what servlet container/app server you are using to run your Java application. I've re-tagged your question to hopefully get it some additional exposure. Here are some resources which may help you out:

- [Session affinity on load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885515/session-affinity-on-load-balancer)
- [what are some good "load balancing issues" to know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570971/what-are-some-good-load-balancing-issues-to-know)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29#Persistence

Comment: Thank you Steven for your comments! I am sure there is no issue on my load balancer as I am displaying the server name in the footer of jsp page and it is keeping the session on the same server. The moment is refresh the page, session values are read so if someone can tell me a way to refresh just once the page the moment page is loaded, it would be one of the workaround for me. We are using F5 load balancer. Running the application on JBoss 5.0 EAP, struts 2.0.

Comment: If you're absolutely certain that your load balancer is routing requests properly, then you'll need to provide more information.